# The key(s) in the keyring /dev/null are ignored as the file has an unsupported filename extension

Tags: kali-linux, gnome-keyring

I am running kali linux. I have been getting following error while updating repositories for long time:

```
(root㉿kali)-[~]
└─# sudo apt-get update  
Hit:1 http://kali.cs.nycu.edu.tw/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
W: http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/InRelease: The key(s) in the keyring /dev/null are ignored as the file has an unsupported filename extension
```

This is my **source.list**

```
See https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free

# Additional line for source packages
# deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
#deb http://repo.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib

#deb-src http://repo.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

How do i resloved that ?
Please help me. Ask in comment if you need more information.